# Is it possible to modify Priority option set on Task entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I was able to modify the built-in Priority option set on the Case (Incident) entity, but on the Task entity I don't get the buttons to add/remove/modify option set values. I'd like to add a value for "Critical" in addition to the stock "Low", "Normal", and "High" values. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a undocumented(?) CRM-ism.

Keeping in mind that behind the scenes all activities share the same priority field in the activitypointer table, we can take an educated guess that it is blocking you from editting that field because it is a shared optionset -- but Microsoft seems to have implemented the shared optionset in a proprietary way and have not used their own "existing optionset" feature. (again, I've found no documentation, would love to be proved wrong if anyone has facts on the matter.)

I would have thought perhaps you could edit the base activity's priority optionset but that is not the case either. I think you are simply stuck -- that optionset is blocked. As a workaround you can add a new custom field to the task that you will be able to customize, but it will not be able to be used in generic activity views, only task-specific views.